# How to install a 3rd party module in Python?

Tags: python, module

I really need someone to dumb this down for me.  I'm new to programming and Python, and I'd like to download and install BeautifulSoup.  I thought I had downloaded, unzipped it, and and ran the setup, but when I try to import I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py3e_source\mc video\MC video count.py", line 6, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

When I run the setup, I get in the Python Shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
  File "C:\Python31\lib\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I'm wondering whether I put the module in the right location on my Windows PC, did I skip a step somewhere?

Comment: Issue this command: `python setup.py install`

Comment: what command you are using to install the lib? Or in other words what are the steps you are following to install this lib?

Comment: I found the setup.py and opened it using IDLE and just pressed F5 to run it.

Comment: The better way is to open a command window -> go to the path where this lib is copied -> run command `python setup.py install` (here setup.py is a file which comes with library). Here I am assuming that you already set Python installation path in windows `path`.

Comment: Have you tried LXML from the UCI website - it has a Window's installer so it saves you some misery.

Comment: By the way you don't run setup in the shell (at least I have never done so) you run it in the command window as commented above.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo apt-get install python-bs4

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```

You can try directly installing it using " sudo apt-get install package name " command.